# Create JSON arrays using LINQ

Tags: c#, json, linq

I have a list of objects returning from the database that look like this when serialized using JSON.NET:

```
"[{"Percentage":0.78, "PartCode":"D40", "InspectionCode":"292", "Make":"TOYOTA"}]
{"Percentage":0.18, "PartCode":"6N", "InspectionCode":"292", "Make":"GM"},
{"Percentage":0.57, "PartCode":"6N", "InspectionCode":"F", "Make":"GM"},
{"Percentage":0.49, "PartCode":"D40", "InspectionCode":"F", "Make":"TOYOTA"},
{"Percentage":0.09, "PartCode":"785", "InspectionCode":"KB", "Make":"CHRYSLER"},
{"Percentage":0.09, "PartCode":"705", "InspectionCode":"KB", "Make":"FORD"},
{"Percentage":0.18, "PartCode":"D40", "InspectionCode":"KB", "Make":"TOYOTA"},
{"Percentage":0.61, "PartCode":"D40", "InspectionCode":"KB", "Make":"TOYOTA"},
{"Percentage":0.39, "PartCode":"705", "InspectionCode":"SB", "Make":"FORD"},
{"Percentage":0.31, "PartCode":"6N", "InspectionCode":"SB", "Make":"GM"},
{"Percentage":0.21, "PartCode":"AW7", "InspectionCode":"XE1", "Make":"CHRYSLER"},
{"Percentage":0.27, "PartCode":"705", "InspectionCode":"XE1", "Make":"FORD"},
{"Percentage":0.28, "PartCode":"UX", "InspectionCode":"XE1", "Make":"FORD"},
{"Percentage":0.56, "PartCode":"D40", "InspectionCode":"XE1", "Make":"TOYOTA"}]"
```

I need to create two JSON arrays in this format to pass to HighCharts:

```
var categories = [
{name: "Toyota", categories: ['D40']},
{name: "GM", categories: ['6N']},
{name: "FORD", categories: ['705', 'UX']},
{name: "CHRYSLER", categories: ['AW7','785']}];

var series = [
{name: "292", data = [0.78, 0.18]}
{name: "F", data = [0.57, 0.49]},
{name: "KB", data = [0.09, 0.09, 0.18, 0.61]},
{name: "SB", data = [0.39, 0.31]},
{name: "XE1", data = [0.21, 0.27, 0.28, 0.56]}];
```

So far, I am doing the nested grouping of data, since Make and PartCode are hierarchical data.

```
var query = from d in sortedData
            group d by d.Make into newgroup1
            from newgroup2 in
                (from e in newgroup1
                 group e by e.PartCode)
            group newgroup2 by newgroup1.Key;
```

I am able to see data in a hierarchical format using:

```
foreach (var outergroup in query)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(outergroup.Key);
    foreach (var innergroup in outergroup)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(innergroup.Key);
        foreach (var innerGroupElement in innergroup)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\t\t{0} {1}", innerGroupElement.InspectionCode, innerGroupElement.Percentage);
        }
    }
}
```

But, I am having a hard time understanding what to do further to get to the desired JSON arrays. What steps do I have to take further inorder to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you what you want. Once you group by the Make or InspectionCode, then all the items in that sub-list will contain the data you are looking for.

```
var categories = sortedData.GroupBy(d => d.Make)
                           .Select(g => new 
                           { 
                               name = g.Key, 
                               categories = g.Select(x => x.PartCode).ToArray() 
                           });

var series = sortedData.GroupBy(d => d.InspectionCode)
                       .Select(g => new 
                       { 
                           name = g.Key, 
                           data = g.Select(x => x.Percentage).ToArray() 
                       });

var categoriesAsJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(categories);
var seriesAsJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(series);
```

If you have the data already in memory, converting it to Json is as easy as the last two lines, using [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). If you are sending this out over the wire via a WebAPI endpoint, then you can just have your endpoint return a list which would be the categories or series list objects without having converted them to JSON.

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetCategories()
{
    var categories = GetCategoriesUsingAboveCode();
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, categories);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
            var categories = sortedData
                .GroupBy(i => i.Make)
                .Select(g => new
                {
                    name = g.Key,
                    categories = sortedData
                        .Where(i2 => i2.Make == g.Key)
                        .Select(i2 => i2.InspectionCode)
                });
```